# python regax search

Tags: python, regex

I have to find the last occurrence of an ip address in a string using regex.
I found this

```
addr = re.search(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', program[line])
```

which finds the first occurrence. How can I change it to find the last one?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of either of those questions. To the OP: if this wasn't marked duplicate I could give you a detailed explanation. The definitive answer is `.*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})` where the ip is in capture group 1. So, `if ( (match=re.search(r'.*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', program[line]) ) ip = match.group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(pattern, string)[-1]
```

Comment: I tried this, but I just get an error because the index is out of range...       edit: findall just returns a blank list for some reason, and therefore the [-1] is out of range...

Comment: @DinaGurevich that means there were no matches.